# Reconstructing values from sums over subsets.

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

I'm learning Linear Dynamic System on my own, and I came across an exercise that I have not idea how to relate to some of the course material I'm learning from (Boyd youtube course). Thank you for any help, the problem is the following:

There are real numbers u1, . . . , up that we do not know, but want to find. We do
have information about sums of some subsets of the numbers. Specifically, we know
v1, . . . , vq, where vi = Sum_j∈Si uj.

Here, Si denotes the subset of {1, . . . , p} that defines the partial sum used to form vi.(We know both vi and Si, for i = 1, . . . , q.) We call the collection of subsets S1, . . . , Sq informative if we can determine, or reconstruct, u1, . . . , up without ambiguity, from v1, . . . , vq. If the set of subsets is not informative, we say it is uninformative.

As an example with p = 3 and q = 4, v1 = u2 + u3, v2 = u1 + u2 + u3, v3 = u1 + u3, v4 = u1 + u2.
This corresponds to the subsets S1 = {2, 3}, S2 = {1, 2, 3}, S3 = {1, 3}, S4 = {1, 2}.

This collection of subsets is informative. To see this, we show how to reconstruct u1, u2, u3. First we note that u1 = v2 − v1. Now that we know u1 we can find u2 from u2 = v4 − u1 = v4 − v2 + v1. In the same way we can get u3 = v3 − u1 = v3 − v2 + v1.

Note: this is only an example to illustrate the notation.

(a) This subproblem concerns the following specific case, with p = 6 numbers and q = 11 subsets. The subsets are:
S1 = {1, 2, 3}, S2 = {1, 2, 4}, S3 = {1, 2, 6}, S4 = {1, 3, 5}, S5 = {1, 4, 5}, S6 = {2, 3, 6}, S7 = {2, 4, 6}, S8 = {3, 4, 5}, S9 = {3, 5, 6}, S10 = {4, 5, 6}, S11 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.
The associated sums are:
v1 = −2, v2 = 14, v3 = 6, v4 = 4, v5 = 20, v6 = −5, v7 = 11, v8 = 9, v9 = 1, v10 = 17, v11 = 15.

Choose one of the following:
• The collection of subsets S1, . . . , S11 is informative.
Justify why you believe this is the case, and reconstruct u1, . . . , u6.

• The collection of subsets S1, . . . , S11 is uninformative. To justify this, give two different sets of values u1, . . . , u6, and u˜1, . . ., u˜6, whose given subset sums agree with the given v1, . . . , v11.

(b) This subproblem concerns a general method for reconstructing u = (u1, . . . ,up) given v = (v1, . . . , vq) (and of course, the subsets S1, . . . , Sq).
We define the subset count matrix Z ∈ R p×p
as follows: Zij is the number of subsets containing both i and j. (Thus, Zii is the number of subsets that contain i.)
For each i, we define fi as the sum of all vj
, over subsets that contain i:
fi = Sum_i∈Sj vj , i = 1, . . . , p.

Then we reconstruct u as u = (Z^−1)f. (Of course, this requires that Z is invertible.)

Choose one of the following:

• The method works, whenever the collection of subsets is informative.
By ‘works’ we mean that Z is invertible, and that (Z^−1)f is the unique u with subset sums v. If you believe this is the case, explain why.

• The method can fail, even when the collection of subsets is informative. To convince us of this, give a specific example, where the collection of subsets is informative, but the method above fails, i.e., either Z is singular, or (Z^−1)f
does not have the required subset sums. (Please give us the simplest example
you can think of.)

Comment: You haven't actually stated a question, have you? Also, your post would look much better if you would use MathJax to format the mathematics. There's help with doing this, available via the Help menu. Note also that in your example $S_{11}$ is superfluous, as it's the union of $S_1$ and $S_{10}$ (also $S_2$ and $S_9$, and so on).

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you for your observations. I edited the post and the question is clearer now. Regarding the math equations, I'll do my best in the next post, I'm going to learn a bit of LaTex.

Comment: For (a), I get uninformative: $u_1=3+t$, $u_2=3-2t$, $u_3=-8+t$, $u_4=8+t$, $u_5=9-2t$, $u_6=t$, $t$ arbitrary.

Comment: So, how does that look.

Comment: Have you lost interest?